# Having trouble understanding the steps of this half angle identity

Tags: analysis, induction

[image]

How does the solution go from 
$\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)}$
to $4\cos^2(\ldots)$? Where does the $4$ come from? I understand that the identity is $\cos^2(2x) = \cos(1+\cos(2x))/2$, but still lost on the $4$.

Comment: The $4$ was there all along. Just replace $\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(\pi/2^{n+1}))$ by $\cos^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$. Don't touch the $4$ :)

Comment: I think there's an extra $\cos$ in the last equation. I did not remove it, but you can edit it yourself if you agree it was not intended to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The half-angle identity states $$\cos^2 \frac{x}{2} = \frac{1+\cos x}{2},$$ which is the algebraic rearrangement of the double-angle identity $$\cos 2\theta = 2 \cos^2 \theta - 1.$$  Thus, with the choice $x = \pi/2^n$, we immediately obtain the desired transformation.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact is that

$$ 2 = 4 \cdot \frac12.$$

Therefore you can substitute for the first $2$ in 
$\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)}$
as follows:

$$\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)} =
\sqrt{4 \cdot \frac12\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)}.$$

And then you can apply the trig identity $\cos^2(2x) = \frac12(1+\cos(2x))$
to $\frac12\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)\right)$,
using $\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ as $2x$.